# FFMPEG and FFPlay can access rtsp stream from one ip, but from other ip, it can't

Tags: ffmpeg, tcp, udp

The situation is kind of complex. I was archiving several CCTV camera feeds (rtsp, h264, no audio) through OpenCV, which worked but the CPU utilization was too high and started to lose some frames time by time.

To reduce the CPU utilization, I started to use FFMPEG to skip the decoding and encoding processes, which worked perfectly on my home machine. However, when I connected to my university VPN and tried to deploy it on our lab server, FFmpeg couldn't read any frame, ffplay couldn't get anything either. However, OpenCV, VLC Player and IINA Player could still read and display the feed.

In Summary,

1 FFMPEG/ffplay

1.1 can only read the feed from my home network(Wi-Fi, optimum)

1.2 from other two networks, the error message says: "Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264, none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options"

2 IINA/VLC Player, OpenCV
These tools can get the video all the time.

I'm wondering whether it's related to some specific port access, that the ffmpeg required but the others don't. I'd appreciate it if anyone can provide any suggestions.

As references, the tested ffplay command is simple:

```
ffplay 'the rtsp address'
```

Thanks

---

Update

More tests have been performed.

By specifying rtsp_transport as TCP, ffplay can play the video, but FFmpeg can't access the video. (In the beginning, when both FFmpeg and ffplay worked through my home network, it was UDP)
The FFmpeg command is as follows:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://the_ip_address/axis-media/media.amp -hide_banner -c:v copy -s 1920x1080 -segment_time 00:30:00 -f segment -strftime 1 -reset_timestamps 1 -rtsp_transport tcp "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S_Test.mp4"
```

Please help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by forcing it to use "-rtsp_transport tcp" right before -i.

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://the_ip_address/axis-media/media.amp -hide_banner -c:v copy -s 1920x1080 -segment_time 00:30:00 -f segment -strftime 1 -reset_timestamps 1 "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S_Test.mp4"
```